# 'Extra argument in call'

Tags: swift

I am getting an error in my super.init as soon as I call an Enum data type from a super class. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class Atleta : Pessoa {

    var beltRanking : Int = 1
    let previousGraduation : Date
    var nextGraduation : Date

    init(beltRanking: Int, previousGraduation: Date, nextGraduation: Date) {

        self.beltRanking = 1
        self.previousGraduation = previousGraduation
        self.nextGraduation = nextGraduation

        super.init(name: name, country: country, birthDay: birthDay, email: email, joiningDate: joiningDate, role: RolePessoa) {

            self.name = name
            self.country = country
            self.birthDay = birthDay
            self.email = email
            self.joiningDate = joiningDate
            let role = RolePessoa()

        }

    }
```

Enum declaration on another file/class:

```
enum RolePessoa {
    case Aluno
    case Funcionario
    case Instrutor
    case Visitante
}
```

Here's the Pessoa class:

```
class Pessoa {

    var bodyStats : BodyStats = BodyStats()
    let name : String
    let country : String
    let birthDay : Date
    let email : String
    let joiningDate : Date
    var role : RolePessoa

    //    var typeOfCar : CarType = .Coupe

    init(name: String, country: String, birthDay: Date, email: String, joiningDate: Date, role: RolePessoa) {

        self.name = name
        self.country = country
        self.birthDay = birthDay
        self.email = email
        self.joiningDate = joiningDate
        self.role = .Aluno

    }

}
```

Comment: And your call to `super.init` has the wrong syntax. You don't add the `{ ... }` part to the call.

Comment: You should look at in the Swift book for the proper syntax. See [Designated and Convenience Initializers in Action](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID223)

Comment: I absolutely Absolutely will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue description**

There are brackets in the code after the `super.init(name: name, country: country, birthDay: birthDay, email: email, joiningDate: joiningDate, role: RolePessoa)` method call in `Atleta` class. Swift compiler thinks that it is a closure passed as the last parameter.

**Solution**

The intention here was to call `super.init` method and pass correct parameters there. We can change the method call to fulfil the goal:

```swift
super.init(name: name, country: country, birthDay: birthDay, email: email, joiningDate: joiningDate, role: .Aluno)
```

Note, that we are passing `.Aluno` as a role as it is used in the `Pessoa` class initializer anyway.

**Refactoring suggestion**

You might want to remove the `role` from initializer parameters to simplify the code or assign the default value to it like this:

```swift
init(name: String, country: String, birthDay: Date, email: String, joiningDate: Date, role: RolePessoa = .Aluno) {

    self.name = name
    self.country = country
    self.birthDay = birthDay
    self.email = email
    self.joiningDate = joiningDate
    self.role = role
}
```

Then super init call can be changed in a next way:

```swift
super.init(name: name, country: country, birthDay: birthDay, email: email, joiningDate: joiningDate)
```

Note, that in this case, we don't specify `role` at all as it is assigned `.Aluno` by default.
We can also specify a different role if needed:

```swift
super.init(name: name, country: country, birthDay: birthDay, email: email, joiningDate: joiningDate, role: .Funcionario)
```

There is good official documentation about initializers to read for beginners: [Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html).

Comment: You are overlooking the fact that the call to `super.init(name: name, ...)` is referencing non-existent variables. The extraneous block is only the first of several issues.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. The title of the question is about `'Extra argument in call'`, so the answer suggests how to solve that problem. I don't think that we have enough information, for now, to suggest what to use instead of the missing values. Do you think, we should mention this in the answer?